# Forwarding sftp with iptables?

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a following configuration:

internet -> iptables server (also have ssh server) -> local computer (ssh server)

How can I open port 8822 for access from internet to local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8822 -j DNAT --to-destination localIP:22
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -d localIP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```